Detect that Immersive Space is dismissed
When the immersive space is dismissed by actions outside my app, how can I detect that happened and execute code based on that?
I need to be able to reset the scene and allow the user to relaunch the immersive space after they dismiss the scene by answering alerts from another app, or pressing the button on top of the headset. But I don't know how to detect that has occurred.

You can use onDismiss
    ImmersiveSpace(id: "ImmersiveSpace") {
        ImmersiveView()
            .onDisappear {
                isShowingImmersive = false
            }
    }

or better yet scenePhase
struct ImmersiveView: View {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase
    @Binding var isShowingImmersive: Bool
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            // Add the initial RealityKit content
            if let scene = try? await Entity(named: "Immersive", in: realityKitContentBundle) {
                content.add(scene)
            }
        }.task(id: scenePhase) {
            switch scenePhase {
            case .inactive, .background:
                isShowingImmersive = false
            case .active:
                isShowingImmersive = true
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

You can use .task(id:) to do things when the Scene is being shown or not.

I think .onChange(of: scenePhase) might be more appropriate than .task(id: scenePhase).

@Drew onChange is known for not catching all changes, especially with scenePhase
